# How to share the interface of a class without disclosing the entire source (like .h files) in Java

Tags: java, plugins, interface, header-files

I'm building a plugin-based program in Java, whereby I want to keep the project closed-source, but allow 3rd-party developers to create plugins. The system I'm using is working, but only because I (of course) have full access to the source code.

Basically, the plugins inherit from Plugin.java, and they may make use of ServerManager.java in order to perform certain critical functions. How do I make it such that users are able to see the interface of these classes (i.e. they know that ServerManager has a sendMessage() function and that Plugin classes can override an onMessage() function) without supplying them with the full source.

Coming from an Objective-C background, I'd use .h files for these "interfaces" and .m files for the source (private) – I'd then only supply the .h files – obviously in Java there's no such thing as a .h file though!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to create an *interface*, let that be public, and provide an implementation of that interface.

For example:

```
interface Light{
    void turnOn();
    void turnO();
    void setBrightness(int newValue);
    void setTimer(int timeoutSeconds);
}
```

Then you define your actual class in a private file:

```
class MyLight implements Light {
    void turnOn() {
      // implementation
    }
    // etc..
}
```

You can provide a Factory class that churns out MyLight objects for the user.

Comment: Looks great actually... I had considered this but wasn't sure if it was *the* way to go. I'll give it a go now and see what happens, marking as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For that java has the [SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html), Service Provider Interface. Here an [article](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3848881/Service-Provider-Interface-Creating-Extensible-Java-Applications.htm).

The mechanism is having an **interface**, publically available, best in its own library.

The (several) implementors provide a jar, with one (or more) implementing classes specified in a text file with the interface name under META-INF.

Then java has an API to pick one implementation, or list all.

It is a relative simple and versatile mechanism, look into the official javadoc. For XML implementations it is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that anyone doesn't see your core code then you can obfuscate the required code, the part you want to expose to client to create a plugin can be skipped from obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

You can dot the similar thing here. Crate an opensource interface and the client will do the implementations on his side.

Most of the java EE world works this way. For example you have a interface definitions like this http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/index.html and have multiple different vendor imepmentations. Similarly your code will have an interfaces that you would use to access the plugins.

One similar implementation is done by Atlassian Confluence where the product is closed source unless you have a specific licence for the source but the plugin development is  completely separated : https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+Plugin+Guide